# Pydrake: Using InverseKinematics with MultibodyPlant of floating and welded bodies mandates extra plants? Alternative: model as arg?

Tags: python, drake

| drake 1.9.0 | python 3.7 | OS: ubuntu 20.04 | pycharm |

I have a Kuka arm welded to world that is knocking around some primitive bodies that are not welded to a frame (cubes, cylinders, etc.)

I currently utilize InverseKinematics(plant, plant_context) to validate the feasibility of Cartesian trajectory requests given to my robot.

I can execute this successfully using (2) plants:
(1) "collision_plant" includes everything in my simulation to be modeled
(2) "robot_plant" is just a MultibodyPlant that is only the kuka and is only used for loading into IK to ensure IK is only solved for states of interest (i.e. the states of my robot)

Using one plant alone induces a dimensional mismatch, I assume caused by my mixing of welded and non-welded bodies in a single plant. Is this assumption correct?

Could model be implemented as an addt'l argument to InverseKinematics to allow it to only calculate IK for a particular model (i.e. just my robot) in a plant?

Comment: A lot of times, if you search the Drake issues database, you will find lots of detailed information on a topic.  See https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/12849 for some discussion of this case.